# OpenGL SDL LINK error MSVCRT.lib

Tags: c++, opengl, dll, visual-studio-2013

Trying to set up an OpenGL environment in visual studio 2013 on windows 7 using SDL, glew, and glm. Yes, I have correctly linked and sorted all of the header and dlls, I have SDL2.dll and glew32.dll with the .exe. My linker input includes opengl32.lib. Runtime Library is set to "Multi-threaded DLL".

```
/*main.cpp*/
#include <SDL.h>
#include <glew.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

the error is

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function     ___tmainCRTStartup   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OpenGLProject\OpenGLProject\MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)  OpenGLProject

I notice that I am able to compile if I comment out `#define main SDL_main` in SDL_main.h, so that might be related to the problem; though I feel as though I am barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: Are project settings set to graphics application and not console one? Judging by function name (`_main`), it isn't. Graphics entry point is `WinMain`, and it is defined in `SDLmain` (so you don't need to define your own).

Comment: Yeah I've already tried setting the subsytem to Windows. In the meantime, I've actually tried running it without it providing its own WinMain by defining `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` and then looking through the source and just copying and pasting the main they provided (which by the way is `int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR szCmdLine, int sw)`)directly into my main.cpp. this compiles, but the moment I call something like `SDL_SetMainReady();` there is a linker error.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly (it's been a while since I last used SDL on Windows), you also have to add a library called `SDLmain` (or similar). This library defines the `main` function, which does some pre-initialization and then calls `SDL_main` which happens to be your "main" function.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, as the upstair said, **add SDL2main.lib to the project** solve the problem, be sure you add the SDL2.LIB && SDL2main.lib in the same time